# How to use a PHP checkbox form to SELECT from MySQL datatype SET (multiple choice) column values?

Tags: php, mysql, dataset, sqldatatypes

I have a MySQL database with a column of datatype SET (multiple selection, say apples, oranges, grapes)

I want to have a form with checkboxes for those values (apples, oranges, grapes etc) so one can select a breakfast basket type that contains for example, oranges and grapes.

It would pull from the database those baskets with those selection of fruits (specified in the column 'Fruits', which is a EM datatype column. (I have a multiple selection when entering the values for the column.)

Can it be done? Should I make another table with FruitNames?

Also, when I add a new value to the multiple selection list, all my previous entries disappear and I have to re-enter all the values again...
Please help!

- How to search for those entries that match the multiple selection (from the SET type column)?
- Can I edit the list of values in the SET type column without erasing previous entries?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will need another table. That is called [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Can you show me query that adds values to list?

I will give you PHP code how to implement selection of fruits.

```
$fruits = implode(',', $_POST['fruits']);
mysql_query('SELECT name, fruit_id FROM fruits WHERE fruit_id IN ('.$fruits.')');
```

Here is the form

```
<input type="checkbox" name="fruits[1]"> Apple<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="fruits[2]"> Pear<br>
```

Comment: Its only demo, c'mon. And it easy to solv this problem:

`foreach($_POST['fruits'] as $key=>$fruit) { $_POST['fruits'][$key] = intval($fruit); }`

Comment: @Ernestas Thanks a lot Ernestas, I was trying to keep the data from the SET column. Found some info online (http://www.freeopenbook.com/mysqlcookbook/mysqlckbk-CHP-18-SECT-4.html). It's indeed basic and easy, I'm just learning.. and the online community is awesome. Thanks again.